# grails - afterDelete() accessing domain properties

Tags: grails, properties, grails-domain-class

Assuming I have got the following domain class and its corresponding history domain class in order to automatically save any changes made to the original domain object:

```
@Entity
class Product {

    String productName 

    static constraints = {
        productName maxSize: 250
    }

    def afterInsert() {
        History_Product hist = new History_Product(this)
        hist.insertType = 'I'
        History_Product.withNewSession {
            hist.save()
        }
    }

    def afterUpdate() {
        History_Product hist = new History_Product(this)
        hist.insertType = 'U'
        History_Product.withNewSession {
            hist.save()
        }
    }

    def afterDelete() {
        History_Product hist = new History_Product(this)
        hist.insertType = 'D'
        History_Product.withNewSession {
            hist.save()
        }
    }
}

@Entity
class History_Product {

    String productName
    Char insertType

    static constraints = {
        productName nullable: true, maxSize: 250
    }

    History_Product() {}

    History_Product(Product p) {
        this.properties = p.properties
    }
}
```

So, every time a `Product` object is created, updated or deleted a new `History_Product` is created in order to save the old value. This works like a charm for creating and updating. However, it doesn't work if I want to delete a product because then `p.properties` wihtin the second constructor of `History_Product` contains only `NULL` values. I don't know where the difference ist between the `afterInsert`, the `afterUpdate` and the `afterDelete` methods. I also tried to use the `beforeDelete` method in case of delete but without success.

Any guesses?

EDIT:

I now checked if I can access the `properties` directly within `afterUpdate` or `afterDelete`. So I added `println this.properties` as first line in each of the two methods. Interestingly, that works find for `afterUpdate` but doesn't for `afterDelete`. What could be the reason? In my controller I've just put `productInstance.delete flush:true`.

2nd EDIT:

Most interestingly, within `afterDelete` I can retrieve the value of `productName`. No matter if I use only `productName` or `this.productName`. Hence, the object is not "empty". Anyway, I don't know why the `properties` map is `NULL`.

3rd EDIT:

I now added `println productInstance.properties` within the controllers `delete` action before I actually delete the `productInstance`. And with this it works. Does anyone has got some kind of explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have to beg your pardon. I withheld some information which obviously was crucial to the problem's solution - I didn't expect it to be important. So here is what I've finally found out:

My class `Product` had a one-to-many relation with another class called `ProductDetail`. Therefore, within `Product` I have `static hasMany = [productDetails:ProductDetail]`. And the `ProductDetail` domain class looked similar to this:

```
@Entity
class ProductDetail {
    Product product
}
```

I can't remember why but obviously I forgot to put `static belongsTo=[product:Product]` instead of the `Product product` line written above.

Eventually, changing that single line resolved my problem and finally I could access the `properties` of the `Product` object.

By the way, it is not relevant if a `ProductDetail` object exists or not. If the `belongsTo` is missing it's not possible to access the `properties` property on the `Product` side.

Comment: I dont see how this is relevant since the belongsTo property only specifies that save and delete should be propagated to ProductDetail.